# Dynamically Add js file at the end of the page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, tags, document

I want to add one js file at the bottom of the page before `</body>` tag.

I am trying one format. But its not working properly.

My code

```
var url = 'sample.js';
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
```

But its not working.

Now i check

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
alert(x.length);
```

its shows `0`

How can i add this js file into my bottom of the page. Please advise

Comment: Your code works as it should. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/CUpuq/, you can check the console also, the script is there. So, what else can it be not working? what are you trying to do besides this code?

Comment: Wait i can send a link to you.

Comment: http://demo.osiztechnologies.com/demo/tooltip/demo2.html @Sergio please see the link and console.

Comment: i don't understand and i am confused. any mistake in my code please advise

Comment: Try `var htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];` without appendChild and then `htmlElement.appendChild(script);` and then `alert(htmlElement.length);`

Comment: By the way, the script you are loading is not a script, its CSS...

Comment: Now i can change to js. but its also not shown in my code

Comment: @Sergio if i am change head instead of body. its working in head section. whats happened here

Comment: CSS should be loaded into head section, it's not allowed in body.

Comment: @Sergio please give me any solution.

Comment: I want to help, but you are changing the code of your link and it's not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/fkGBf/) code

```
var body = document.body;
alert("Body when page loading: " + body);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var bodyLoaded = document.body;
    alert("Body when page loaded: " + bodyLoaded);
    var url = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js";
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = url;
    script.onload = function(){
        var testP = $("<p></p>");
        testP.html("JQuery worked");
        $(document.body).append(testP);
    }
    bodyLoaded.appendChild(script);
});
```

If first `alert` you get `null`. But in second (when body loaded) you get `HTMLBodyElement`. This is your mistake if you try to append element to body in head before body loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing your this code in the head section and at the time this executes body element is not yet created. This is the only reason for error. Keep this code after body element is created.

Comment: but i need to run this script only head section. because i am creating firefox addon. so only i need this method

Comment: I am not sure about your requirement. If you want to write this code only in head section you can add (append ) your this script in head instead of in body??